# python can't find file it just made

Tags: python, file, path

My program cannot find the path that it just made, the program is for sorting files in the download folder.
If it finds a new type of file it should make a folder for that file type.

```
import os

FileList = os.listdir("/sdcard/Download/")
for File in FileList:
    #print File
    extension = ''.join(os.path.splitext(File)[1])
    ext = extension.strip('.')
    if os.path.exists("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext):
        Data = open("/sdcard/Download/" + File, "r").read()
        file("/mnt/external_sd/" + ext + "/" + File, "w").write(Data)
    elif os.path.exists("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext) != True:
        os.makedirs("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext)
        Data = open("/sdcard/Download/" + File, "r").read()
        file("/mnt/external_sd/" + ext + "/" + File, "w").write(Data)
```

Comment: I haven't fooled around in Python for a while, but doesn't this line `os.makedirs("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext)` create a directory, and not a file, which you then try to open?

Comment: @charmlessCoin: Well, he does then append `"/" + File` to it.

Comment: @charmlessCoin yes it does make a directory.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Whoops, just noticed that. Now I see what he's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the directory

```
"/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext
```

but then you are trying to write to

```
"/mnt/external_sd/" + ext + "/" + File
```

You dropped the `Download` folder in that path. Change the last line to:

```
file("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext + "/" + File, "w").write(Data)
```

Incidentally, it would be a bit shorter and clearer to write your last seven lines by taking the shared lines out of the `if` `else` statement and using `shutil.copy` instead of reading in the whole file then writing it out again:

```
import shutil
if not os.path.exists("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext):
    os.makedirs("/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext)
shutil.copy("/sdcard/Download/" + File, "/mnt/external_sd/Download/" + ext + "/" + File)
```

(Using `shutil` will also generally be faster and use less memory, especially if your files are large).

Comment: Thank you for finding that small but somewhat obvious mistake.